# documentRef.get() not executed, simply ignored and passed over

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app should retrieve for the user the single `String field` "itemList" of their `FireStore db` document (named after their `userID`) to a `String variable` "json"

[structure of FireStore db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx0Rq.png)

```
 if (currentUser != null) {

        Log.d(TAG, "userID = " + currentUser.getUid());
        
        documentRef.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {

                    Log.d(TAG, "success");
                    
                    json = documentSnapshot.getString("itemList");                        

                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {

                    Log.d(TAG, "failure");                        

                });

    }
```

The first log prints the proper `userID`, so the connection and authentication with Firebase are made.

**But `documentRef.get()` is never executed** (none of its two logs is printed). "json" remains indeed `null`, though an inspection through `Firebase Console` shows "itemList" contains the `String` data it is supposed to.

`documentRef` is initiated as

```
FirebaseFirestore db;
DocumentReference documentRef;
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
documentRef = db.collection("Users").document(currentUser.getUid());
```

which is preceded by the authentication section:

```
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseUser currentUser;    
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
```

And these are the `FireStore security rules`:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Users/{userID} {
      allow create, read, write, delete : if request.auth.uid == userID;
    }   
 }   
}
```

So it looks like `documentRef.get()` is being entirely ignored. There are **no error messages**. Of course, futher down the road, when it starts to use "json", the app throws a `nullPointerException`, because "json" has remained `null`.

I tried on both a virtual device in `Android Studio` and a real phone.

What is wrong?

PS: writing `String` data to "itemList" with `documentRef.set()` was no problem, as confirmed through `Firebase Console`. It is actually this data the app is trying to retrieve.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Do you have the proper rules for reading data from Firestore?

Comment: If neither onSucces nor onFailure fires, then are you sure you have an internet connection on the user's device?

Comment: App gave the same result on both a virtual device in Android Studio and a real device. This arguably rules out internet connectivity being the cause.